# What is the value of a summation with a larger index than it's stopping value n.

Tags: summation

$\Sigma_{i_=n+1}^n$  I think the result will be 0 right ?

My reasoning being since this would be a summation of an empty sequence.

Comment: It's usually defined to be 0, but you can define it however you see fit.

Comment: @Dzoooks how do you mean? could you give an example ?

Comment: Remember that if we interchange the endpoints on a definite integral, we negate the value. So, be careful, context matters.